# Faster R-CNN is slower in Realtime prediction

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am trying to detect objects using Tensorflow Object Detection API. Have worked on both SSD and Faster R-CNN. SSD is fast when compared to Faster R-CNN. But in SSD I cannot able to detect objects in Longer distance, in Faster R-CNN I can able to acheive it.

But the only problem is that Faster R-CNN is very very slow in Real-time Prediction (using webcam).

I have tried to implement MultiThreading mentioned [here](https://nrsyed.com/2018/07/05/multithreading-with-opencv-python-to-improve-video-processing-performance/) to speed up the prediction process, but there was no improvement.

1. Can someone help to speed up Realtime prediction with Faster R-CNN?
2. Can Faster R-CNN be able to run on GPU? if possible please guide me on how to achieve that